# Convert huge CSV to Parquet with partition using glue

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have an Athena CSV table partitioned by month, I want to convert this CSV to parquet with day partition using AWS glue.

Following is my source table in Athena,

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.csv_table (
col1 STRING,
col2 STRING,
event_time_stamp STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (month string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "quoteChar" = "\"", "escapeChar" = "\\" )
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test/csv/
```

S3 has following structure partitioned by month,

```
s3://mybucket/test/csv/month=01/somefile.gz
s3://mybucket/test/csv/month=02/somefile.gz
```

I want to convert above CSV to parquet in-order to work with following structure - partitioned by date instead of month, the date partition needs to be extracted from event_time_stamp column

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.parquet_table (
col1 STRING,
col2 STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "quoteChar" = "\"", "escapeChar" = "\\" )
LOCATION 's3://mybucket/test/parquet/
```

I tried to convert using following scripts it doesn't seems to work.

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="mydb",
    table_name="csv_table", 
    transformation_ctx="datasource0"
)
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=datasource0, 
    mappings=[
        ("col1", "string", "col1", "string"), 
        ("col2", "string", "col2", "string"), 
        ("month", "string", "month", "string")
    ], 
    transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"
)
selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(
    frame=applymapping1, 
    paths=["col1", "col2"],
    transformation_ctx="selectfields2"
)
resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(
    frame=selectfields2,
    choice="MATCH_CATALOG",
    database="mydb",
    table_name="parquet_table",
    transformation_ctx="resolvechoice3"
)
resolvechoice4 = ResolveChoice.apply(
    frame=resolvechoice3, 
    choice="make_struct",
    transformation_ctx="resolvechoice4"
)
datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = resolvechoice4, 
    connection_type="s3", 
    connection_options={
        "path":"s3://mybucket/test/csv/", 
        "partitionKeys": ["day"]
    }, 
    format="parquet",  
    transformation_ctx=datasink5
)
job.commit()
```

I am a new big to GLUE

Comment: You need to have day as a column in your source data or you have to derive this column in your Glue job.Do you have any other date/time related columns in your data other than month because date cannot be calculated just from month column.

Comment: @bdcloud yes, I have a column called event_time_stamp in source (Sorry I forgot to mention in source columns) which will contains the event_time_stamp in string format, so is there is any way to extract just the date from event_time_stamp column and use this as partition column?

Comment: Do you have to use Glue ETL job? Is you dataset fixed, meaning is it a one time thing that you need to do or your data gets constantly uploaded for new days/months? Your conversion seems pretty simple for which I would opt out for Athena CTAS queries. I can elaborate on this if you are interested.

Comment: For some reason I would like to stick with AWS Glue